# pyswip python/django segmentation fault

Tags: python, django, prolog, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault while trying to use pyswip with Django.

My config :

```
Linux 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs #1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Python 3.6.4 # latest Python's docker image
Django 2.0.2
SWI-Prolog 6.6.6
pyswip 0.2.7
```

Test in the shell works like a charm :

```
$python manage.py shell
>>>from pyswip import Prolog
>>>prolog = Prolog()
>>>prolog.assertz('person(john)')
>>>print(list(prolog.query('person(X)')))
[{'X': 'john'}]
```

Whereas in a django view, I get a segmentation fault as soon as the ...

```
prolog.assertz('person(john)')
```

... is processed.

Can't find a solution to this problem so far (best trail up to now : [pyswip - issue #1](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyswip/issues/1)). Is there a configuration in the settings.py for example to add ? What's missing for django's ecosystem to process that instruction right?